# TypeScript null checks not paying attention to array.length check

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, null, type-inference

When compiling TypeScript using strict null checks, the following does not type check even though it's fine:

```
const arr: number[] = [1, 2, 3]
const f = (n: number) => { }
while (arr.length) {
    f(arr.pop())
}
```

The compilation error is:

> Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type 'number'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type
>   'number'.

It seems that the compiler isn't smart enough to know that `arr.pop()` will definitely return a number.

Some questions:

1. Why isn't the compiler smarter? Would adding smarter null-checking for this kind of case be incredibly difficult, or is it something straightforward that the TS team hasn't implemented yet?
2. What's the most idiomatic way to write the above that still type-checks?

Re 2, the best I can come up with is to add a superfluous check to the body of the loop:

```
while (arr.length) {
    const num = arr.pop()
    if (num) { // make the compiler happy
        f(num)
    }
}
```

Comment: It is correct, when you do a pop and it does not have any elements to return. It returns a null, that is why it has this as a return type "number | undefined" in the case if the element is empty.

Comment: Use `f(arr.pop() as number)` should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried build your code on `typescript@2.5.3` with `"awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.3"`, it doesn't have any compiling error.

Comment: @FisNaN, you need to enable strict null checks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes adding this kind of smartness to compiler is considered difficult, see [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11095#issuecomment-249328521) on the very exact issue that describes your problem.

In the meanwhile, you can use [non-null assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) - postfix `!` - to tell the compiler that you know that the value is not null:

```
const arr: number[] = [1, 2, 3]
const f = (n: number) => { }
while (arr.length) {
    f(arr.pop()!)
}
```